# How to remove unknown virtual device in Android Studio

Tags: android, windows, android-studio

I used to develop apps using Android Studio.

I have a strange issue but I don't know the reason and solution.

[unknown virtual device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpN65.png)

I want to remove this hateful "device".

I removed it for "Action/remove" but after restarting Android Studio, it appeared again.

Must I stand for it? Or is there any solution?

Comment: Try this: AVD manager -> actions -> show on Disk -> close Android Studio -> delete the folder. At least now you know it's not wasting any space.

Comment: "AVD manager->actions->show on Disk" doesn't open any folder, no action.